# PanacheReactive on Scheduled IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to execute a stupid query from `@Scheduled` method using an `ApplicationScoped` `PanacheRepository`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyRepo implements PanacheRepository<MyEntity> {
```

then I have the following

```
@Inject
MyRepo repo;

@Scheduled(every = "${cache.refreshRate}", delayed = "20s")
public Uni<Void> scheduleRefresh() {
    return repo.listAll().replaceWithVoid();
}
```

And I am getting the following exception

> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Error occurred while executing task for
> trigger IntervalTrigger
> [id=1_org.xx.xxxxx.infrastructure.importer.Importer_ScheduledInvoker_scheduleRefresh_520a27e95be32ee7cfd3163651929119f1ff17fe,
> interval=300000]: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Session/EntityManager is closed at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:407)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:148)
> at
> org.hibernate.reactive.session.impl.ReactiveSessionImpl.checkOpen(ReactiveSessionImpl.java:1558)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpenOrWaitingForAutoClose(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
> at

EDIT

The application runs correctly locally (postgres on docker) but fails on the cloud (gcp + cloudsql)

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: @geoand I am currently using 2.10.1

Comment: GCP requires a socket factory (see https://github.com/cescoffier/polycloud-demo/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties#L9). I don't know if the reactive driver supports that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Quarkus.

This workaround should work:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SchedulerBean {

    @Inject
    Mutiny.SessionFactory factory;

    @Scheduled(every = "${cache.refreshRate}", delayed = "20s")
    Uni<Void> scheduleRefresh() {
        return factory.withSession( SchedulerBean::refresh );
    }

    private static Uni<Void> refresh(Mutiny.Session s) {
        return s.createQuery( "from MyEntity" ).getResultList().replaceWithVoid();
    }
}
```

You can rewrite it with criteria, if you prefer something programmatic:

```
    private static Uni<Void> refresh(Mutiny.Session s) {
            CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = factory
                    .getCriteriaBuilder()
                    .createQuery( MyEntity.class );
            query.from( MyEntity.class );
            return s.createQuery( query ).getResultList().replaceWithVoid();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the workaround. Is this a bug on quarkus 2.10.x? If i downgrade to 2.9.x will I get the correct behaviour ?

Comment: I don't think it's going to work. You can try and let us know.I think it's an issue related to using CDI + Panache reactive that was pre-existent. Basically, the session is in the request context scope and doesn't get closed at the right time. When you use `withSession`, you are actually sure that the session gets open and close at the right time.

Comment: this seems to be working, but I am getting the following warning in the logs `Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 3877 ms` . 
What I found interesting is that the original code works as expected against docker on my local machine but not on gcp against cloudsql

Comment: Are there many elements in the table? It could be that the query is slow. Note that if everything is fast enough (it could be the case locally), you won't see any issue because the operations happen in the right order anyway.

Comment: This is outside the scope of this question, but are you sure this is the best way to refresh the cache? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ~700k records. Table has two columns only. Right now I am just experimenting with quarkus... My expectation was that the event loop would have not been blocking performing that operation

Comment: At the moment, the results of the query are not stream as soon as they are available . This means that, if there are too many results, it might take a lot of time to prepare the result set. Vert.x notices this and log the warning.

Comment: Does it mean that the eventloop can still be handle events ? Can I assume that it is not main to actually querying the database?

Comment: The event loop will not be blocked during the retrieval, but if you plan to process these entries that may be considered blocking (imagine you need one second per entry, then it's 700K seconds, that would not be allowed on the event loop).

Comment: @Blackbelt, if you have more questions about this, [the Quarkus users Zulip chat](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users) is probably the best place to get answers